# How can I get a Jquery/Javascript typewriter to recognize whitespace characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a simple jquery typewriter to recognize whitespace characters like \n and \r so that the resulting text will actually have line breaks. When I try to get the control structure to recognize a '\', nothing runs at all... Any help appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var text = "runtype";
    var count = 0;
    var maxspeed = 200;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      function typeit(userInput) {
        text = userInput;
        type();
      }

      function character(start, end, text) {
        return text.substring(start, end);
      }

      function type(){

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxspeed);
        var char1 = character(count, count+1, text);
        var char2 = character(count+1, count+2, text);
        var whitespace = char1+char2;

        if (char1 === '\\'){
          $('#box').append(whitespace);
          setTimeout(type, 20);
        } else if (char1 === ' '){
          $('#box').append(char1);
          setTimeout(type, 20);
        }else if (char1 === '@'){
          ;
          setTimeout(type, 300);
        } else {
          $('#box').append(char1);
          setTimeout(type, random);
        }

        count++;

    }

    typeit('runtype and \\nruntype and runtype');
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is _#box_ styled? Is it like a `<pre>`? Remember that whitespace collapses in normal _HTML_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whitespace` is the literal string `\n` (`"\\n"`, two characters), not a linebreak. You would need to append an actual whitespace (if that appears because of CSS `white-space: pre-wrap`) or use a `<br/>` element or create a new paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

As you are appending directly to the DOM, whitespace will have no effect (other than adding a single space). Instead you need to append an element to force the new line. In this example I used a `br` tag when a `\n` is encountered in the input string:

```
if (char1 === '\\') {
    if (char2 === 'n') {
        $('#box').append('<br />');
        count++; // to cover the second character of the chord
    }
    /*
    if (char2 === 'something else') {
        More logic for other chords. 
        Could possibly changed to a switch if you've got lots of options.
    }
    */
    setTimeout(type, 20);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bBH37/)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by other answers, new lines in whitespace are ignored in html by default.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw5wz/1/) of your example modified to replace `\n` with `<br/>` to produce new line (in the method call, you must use just single `\`, so that `\n` is recognized as newline, if you use `\\n`, then you escape the backslash to just be backslash).

Another option would be to css style your output with `white-space: pre-wrap;` as shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhRCp/2/).